# Sdcard not showing as folder and unable to create folder in sdcard in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, sd-card, android-sdcard

[image: The DDMS view when running the emulator]

I was trying to create an sdcard and load images onto that. I dont know what command went wrong and now my sdcard is not showing as folder but as in the image. Now i am not able to read the sdcard or add folders or images onto that, because it is showing "mkdir failed, read only file system". I tried with new eclipse new android sdk, but the problem is same. Maybe somewhere in my system the properties have been set. 
I am newbie to android and i am badly stuck. Please help!

[image: Problem with sdcard permission]

I am trying to push images directly .. but its giving me an error on console..

[2012-08-05 15:14:12] Failed to push the item(s).
[2012-08-05 15:14:12] null

Answer (score 1):

Look at your sdcard in `mnt` directory.

Actual location of sdcard is `/mnt/sdcard`.

Comment: Even in the /mnt/sdcard i am unable to make any folders to store my images.. I used >>adb shell >>cd mnt >>cd sdcard >>mkdir pics

Answer (score 0):

Goto mnt folder. There is your sd card folder. Any further questions?

Comment: Even in the /mnt/sdcard i am unable to make any folders to store my images.. I used >>adb shell >>cd mnt >>cd sdcard >>mkdir pics

Comment: Dont make any folders, just send the images through the push data to phone icon (The icon with a phone and a arrow on it).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe missing the permission in AndroidManifest.xml? I know I did :)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE